# How can we formulate the working mathematically of this simple number theory word problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Three friends - Huxley, Geordie and Olly - live together and they all love eating pizza. Huxley has the habit of eating a pizza every 5 days, Geordie every 7 days and Olly every 11 days. Huxley and Olly both eat pizzas together on 3 January 2015 and Geordie has a pizza the next day. When will they all eat pizza together?

My working:
It is intuitive to use the least common multiple. So lcm(5,7,11)=365. But the problem is they don't start on the same day. If we only consider Huxley and Olly, then they will eat pizza every 55 days. So we are looking one day before  those days (H and O eat together and G on the day before) since Geordie has been shifted forward by one day.

I have little clue how can we formulate this mathematically. Can we use modulo arithmetic in some ways?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is some sort of typo, you mention H,G and O in the beginning but then give the stats on O,G, and O...is Oscar=Huxley?

Comment: Yes, I edited it. Thanks @user41728

Answer (score 1):

Let say that 3 January 2015 is the day 0. Then, as you remarked H and O will eat a pizza together every 55 days. So all the days they eat together are something like $55d_1$. Furthermore G ate a pizza on the 4th of January 2015 which is day $1$ and $G$ eats pizza every $7$ days so days where $G$ eat some pizza is something like $1+7d_2$.

At the end you will have to solve $55d_1=1+7d_2$ in $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Mathematically you are just looking for a Bezout Identity.